# How to structure Angular JS with multiple layouts with Express backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, single-page-application

My site has 3 main parts, the landing page, admin panel and a user dashboard

My file structure is divided 2 folders

/client => angular frontend
/server => express api backend

I am consuming one express backend api

Normally in angular, there is a single index.html file in the client side of the application and we are using it for all the routing

But what if i want to divide this as modules, one index.html layout for different parts such as landing, admin and dashboard. because each module has own asssets, resources.. is including all resources in single html page good approach?

How can i overcome this issue? can i use multiple SPAs and connect them together while keeping them use the same api

Any ideas for this problem or how can you handle this in your projects, how can you implement admin panel etc.

my goal is to have something like that for client folder
/client
  /admin
    ...
    index.html
  /landing
    ...
    index.html
  /dashboard
    ...
    index.html

thanks in advance

Comment: You could also break it out to different sites if you wanted to and they really needed to be separate. If you want to have it all in one app, then you should have different states that have the stuff you need. You mention wanting to have many index.html pages. Can you explain the reason for this? Maybe I could better help you with more info.

Comment: @joncodo thanks for the answer i will try to examine it.Firstly, users hit the landing page do signup and login stuff here, after authenticate they can go to their dashboard from landing and also we have an admin panel to manage the whole app, i just thought that because of the all landing, dashboard and admin modules have completely different layouts and resources, serving from one main index.html would be bad approach thats why i wanted to have different main layout files for each part, like different angular apps for each part,  also i want to share common data like sessions etc btw them

Answer (score 0):

I use ui-router for this.

https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

So you make a route called app. Then you make states in each of the folders you want. Set the states to app.client, app.admin and app.other.

Then inherit the stuff you need on each page. All the common stuff goes in index.html.

Does that make sense?

[image: structure]

This project might help to get you started: https://github.com/joncodo/SailsAngularStarter

It uses sails which wraps express. If you have any questions, please open an issue there and I can help you.

In that project, the app folder holds all the frontend stuff and the api folder all the backend stuff. The api routes are in config/routes. The views are in app/states.

Currently, it supports the states internal and login.